# Python ctypes: how to define a callback having a buffer pointer and a length in argument?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, void-pointers

I have a lib (in source form, if it helps) defining, among other things the following function:

```
void subscribe(const char* ip_addr,
               uint16_t port,
               uint32_t token,
               void (*cb)(void *buffer, uint32_t length, uint32_t token)
                  );
```

I defined this in python (v3.10.4, if it matters):

```py
from ctypes import *

so_file = './mylib.so'
lib = CDLL(so_file)

ADDRESS = b"127.0.0.1"
PORT = 21000

data_callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_byte), c_int32, c_int32)

def py_data_callback(buf, bln, tok):
    print(f'Data: [{hexlify(buf, sep=":", bytes_per_sep=4)}] ({bln}|{tok})')

data_callback = data_callback_type(py_data_callback)
ret = lib.subscribe(c_char_p(ADDRESS), c_uint16(PORT), c_int32(42), data_callback)
print(ret)

...
```

Registration and callback apparently work fine, but I'm receiving the pointer itself in the callback and not the content (I think that's consistent with what I coded) as printout looks like:

```
Data: [b'0cc2ddd9:c07f0000'] (24|42)
```

and `b'0cc2ddd9:c07f0000'` looks suspiciously similar to a pointer (I'm on an amd64 machine).

How do I convince `ctypes` to return a `bytes(24)` or, alternatively, given the above pointer how do I access pointed array?

I am new to `ctypes` and I could have missed something in the docs, but I didn't find the answer there.

Comment: does `buf[0:bln]` not work?

Comment: @user253751 not quite: `print(f'Data: [{hexlify(buf[0:bln], sep=":", bytes_per_sep=4)}] ({bln}|{tok})')` rises `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'`. but I think we are closer. A plain `print(f'Data: [{buf[0:bln]}] ({bln}|{tok})')` outputs `Data: [[42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] (24|42)` which does not look right.

Comment: I guess it returns a list of numbers instead of a `bytes`. why not just convert it with `bytes(buf[0:bln])`? haven't used ctypes myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a callback, if `POINTER(c_char)` is used for data (esp. if the data contains nulls), then string slicing works to read the data as a Python byte string.  It's also recommended to set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for functions called by `ctypes`, so it can convert Python-to-C types correctly (and vice versa):

test.c - working example for reproducible testing:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API void subscribe(const char* ip_addr,
                   uint16_t port,
                   uint32_t token,
                   void (*cb)(void *buffer, uint32_t length, uint32_t token)) {
    cb("\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07",8,token);
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_char), c_uint32, c_uint32)

# decorating a Python function makes it usable as a callback
@CALLBACK
def callback(buf, length, tok):
    print(buf[:length])
    print(f'Data: [{buf[:length].hex(sep=":", bytes_per_sep=4)}] ({length}|{tok})')

lib = CDLL('./test')
# correct argument and return types
lib.subscribe.argtypes = c_char_p, c_uint16, c_uint32, CALLBACK
lib.subscribe.restype = None

lib.subscribe(b'127.0.0.1', 21000, 42, callback)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07'
Data: [00010203:04050607] (8|42)
```

*EDIT*
Per comments, below demonstrates how to wrap this all up in a class.  Note that if decoration is used on the unbound class method, the callback won't be called correctly due to `self` being a required parameter.  It's also important that if the *bound* callback is wrapped as shown in `__init__`, then the callback will be wrapped for the lifetime of the use of the class instance.  **Do not** wrap the instance method as it is passed to the `subscribe`, e.g.:

```
self.lib.subscribe(self.ip, self.port, token, CALLBACK(self.callback))
```

because the wrapped object lifetime will end after the `subscribe` call.  If the callback is referenced later, e.g. by the `event` call I've added, it would fail.  Wrapping the bound instance method in `__init__` ensures the wrapping lifetime exists for the lifetime of the instance.

test.c

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(void* buffer, uint32_t length, uint32_t token);

CALLBACK g_cb;
uint32_t g_token;

API void subscribe(const char* ip_addr,
                   uint16_t port,
                   uint32_t token,
                   void (*cb)(void *buffer, uint32_t length, uint32_t token)) {
    g_cb = cb;
    g_token = token;
}

API void event(void* buffer, uint32_t length) {
    if(g_cb)
        g_cb(buffer, length, g_token);
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_char), c_uint32, c_uint32)

class Test:

    lib = CDLL('./test')
    lib.subscribe.argtypes = c_char_p, c_uint16, c_uint32, CALLBACK
    lib.subscribe.restype = None

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.cb = CALLBACK(self.callback)

    def subscribe(self, token):
        self.lib.subscribe(self.ip, self.port, token, self.cb)

    def event(self, data):
        self.lib.event(data, len(data))

    def callback(self, buf, length, tok):
        print(buf[:length])
        print(f'Data: [{buf[:length].hex(sep=":", bytes_per_sep=4)}] ({length}|{tok})')

test = Test(b'127.0.0.1', 21000)
test.subscribe(42)
test.event(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07')
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07'
Data: [00010203:04050607] (8|42)
```

Comment: Is it possible to wrap everything in a class? Specifically: what is the spell to use a `def callback(self, buff, length, tok)` as callback? Done in the "stupid way" it bombs with "TypeError: AudioConsumer.data_cb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tok'" (i.e.: actually `self` is missing, I think)

Comment: @ZioByte You can make the callback a `staticmethod` and pass `self` as an additional parameter if you need to access the class instance data.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Apparently using a method as callback works out-of-thebox (i.e.: no `@staticmethod` and no need for a "fake `self`") if (and only if) I do **not** use the decoration. What am I losing leaving it out?

Comment: @ZioByte Decorating wraps the unbound method, which is why it requires a self parameter when decorated.

Comment: @ZioByte Added an example and a caveat about wrapping manually to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctypes.string_at`:

```
buf_data = ctypes.string_at(buf, bln)
```

Despite the name, this returns a `bytes`, not a string

(Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)